# How do I install "non-free firmware" (wifi driver) from USB? (Debian)

Tags: debian, debian-installer, iwlwifi

I just installed Debian on laptop, it tells me

> Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate. The firmware can be loaded from removable media, such as a USB stick or floppy.
>
> The missing firmware files are: iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
>
> If you have media available now, insert it, and continue.
>
> Load missing firmware from removable media?

Using minimal Debian iso and no mirror I was able to install terminal only. Two questions:

1. Where do I download these files?
2. How do I get Debian to recognize them once on flash drive? Grep?
3. Do I need to do special formatting or partitioning to flash drive?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See [the relevant section in the installation manual](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s04.en.html).

To answer your questions in more detail:

1. You'll find the files on http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/; if you're installing Debian 8, look in http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/jessie/current/ and download whichever archive is the easiest for you to handle (presumably [firmware.tar.gz](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/jessie/current/firmware.tar.gz) or [firmware.zip](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/jessie/current/firmware.zip)).
2. Extract the firmware archive in the root of a flash drive; plug the drive into the computer you're installing, and the installer should find the firmware automatically.
3. The typical FAT32 filesystem is just fine. If you've got a larger drive using ExFAT, I'm not sure the installer will be able to use it...

Comment: ExFAT is not supported yet (in Debian 9.4.0)

Answer (score 2):

Debian offers convenient boot images including the non-free firmware blobs, so one doesn't need to create a second partition on boot media or use secondary usb media.

https://cdimage.debian.org/images/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/

This quickens the install media creation ceremony.