# Network firmware is missing

Tags: linux, kali-linux

Can someone help me I went to install kali linux, and it is missing this firmaware, where can I download it ??

[image]

Comment: If you skip this step, all that will happen is that your wifi adapter won't be initialised. If you have a wired connection you can install the firmware after the installation

Comment: then I will skip this step

Comment: @ilkkachu thanks for the link. I've created an answer and included it there

Answer (score 0):

If you skip this step, all that will happen is that your wifi adapter won't be initialised. If you have a wired connection you can install the firmware after the installation.

See also [How do I install "non-free firmware" (wifi driver) from USB?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/316920/170373) - same principle but different driver