# Second Linux not seen in GRUB

Tags: debian, grub

Some time ago I installed Kali as my first Linux. It's ok and all, but I messed it up a bit, and wanted to install Debian. Now Debian is installed. I can see all the files through Kali, but I cannot see Debian in GRUB. I can only see Kali, Kali Advanced and Windows. How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you try to `sudo update-grub` to regenerate your configuration?

Comment: The `update-grub` also shows, which partitions were found. In `/etc/grub.d` can you find the scripts which look for different partition types. These aren't the best readable scripts I've ever seen, but likely there is the problem.

Comment: Yea, this worked. By the way. Any idea where I can get wifi drivers from?

Comment: @alex3wielki try to take a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249972/how-do-i-install-non-free-firmware-wifi-driver-from-usb-debian/249980#249980), the drivers for Kali and Debian are the same afaik.

Comment: That's why it's strange. Kali had the drivers, and Debian didn't